# access to an array inside a object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have this code in (push notification payload) my application :

```
var payload = {"message":"Bundle[{id=0, title=This is a test 
notification, android.support.content.wakelockid=3, 
collapse_key=push, from=93469011985}]","inBackground":0};
```

And i want to access to the "id" and "title" properties in this JSON.
How can i do this ? thx in advance :)

I have tried to do things like this :

```
console.log (payload.message['id'])
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Hey i parsed your JSON online. But its coming as invalid Json on This Site(http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer).

Comment: that's not a valid json! `Bundle` can't be there.

Comment: You should use regex or substring

Comment: I correct myself: the whole 'message' is a string, there is no array in there. Have a look at the quote-signs!

Comment: @Jeff you are wright ! thinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var id = payload.message.substring(payload.message.indexOf("id=") + 3, payload.message.indexOf(",", payload.message.indexOf("id=")));
var title = payload.message.substring(payload.message.indexOf("title=") + 6, payload.message.indexOf(",", payload.message.indexOf("title=")));
console.log(id, title);//prints 0 This is a test notification
```

**Warning**
This code will fail if you have `,` in the middle of the title.

Comment: @NacimIdjakirene: Glad I helped. But, beware of the warning.